# How to know which event will affect to which tables in database?

Tags: mysql, sql-server

Assume that I have a `application`, with source code and database. I want to know when an `event` occurred, which tables will be `affected`. Is there any tool or technical to do that? I am thinking about `audit log` of database, but I don't know how to link the `event` and the `log` automatically.

**Note:**
 `application` means a website or a Windows app.
`event` means clicked button, typed text box.
`affected database table` means read, insert, update or delete data of the table.

Any suggestion, document of keyword for searching are welcome!

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, @a_horse_with_no_name. The DBMS can be MySQL or SQL Server

Comment: You have two possible sources here. For the button click, you are looking to record history via the UI, or, for the DB call, you are looking to record the request via the DB.  It will depend on how you wish to set the audit up, some teams prefer to use the UI Event to then send a log entry to be stored in DB, others prefer to use either a trigger (with or without SB) or cdc to store the change.  The question is very wide with many possible scenarios and solutions.